CPI ERROR - Error Code: InstructionFallbackNotFound
I'm getting an error when trying to do a cpi:
Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionFallbackNotFound. Error Number: 101. Error Message: Fallback functions are not supported.
i've the following code in a crate:
pub fn set_cfg<'info>(
ctx: CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, xHandler<'info>>,
a: u64,
b: u64,
c: u64,
d: u64,
e: u64,
f: u64,
g: u8,
h: u64,
i:u8,
j: u64,
) -> Result<()> {

//let mut data = hash(b"global:set_cfg").to_bytes()[..8].to_vec();
 let mut data = vec![0xe8, 0xfa, 0xd7, 0xfb, 0xe5, 0xfd, 0xaa, 0x12];
data.extend_from_slice(&a.to_le_bytes());
data.extend_from_slice(&b.to_le_bytes());
data.extend_from_slice(&c.to_le_bytes());
data.extend_from_slice(&d.to_le_bytes());
data.extend_from_slice(&e.to_le_bytes());
data.extend_from_slice(&f.to_le_bytes());
data.extend_from_slice(&[g]);
data.extend_from_slice(&h.to_le_bytes());
data.extend_from_slice(&[i]);
data.extend_from_slice(&j.to_le_bytes());


let ix = Instruction::new_with_borsh(ID, &data, ctx.accounts.to_account_metas(None));

solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
    &ix,
    &[
        ctx.accounts.account_a.clone(),
        ctx.accounts.account_b.clone(),
        ctx.accounts.account_c.clone(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.clone(),
        ctx.accounts.instructions.clone()
    ],
    ctx.signer_seeds,
)
.map_err(Into::into)

}
In the program where i call this cpi i've:
        let accounts = x_programs::modules::xHandler{
        account_a: self.account_a.to_account_info(),
        account_b: self.account_b.to_account_info(),
        account_c: self.account_c.to_account_info(),
        account_d: self.system_program.to_account_info(),
        account_e: self.instructions.to_account_info()
    };

    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
        self.x_program.to_account_info(),
        accounts
    )

    x_program::modules::set_cfg(
        cpi_context,
        a,
        b, 
        c, 
        d, 
        e, 
        f, 
        g, 
        h,
        i,
        j,
     )?;   

In the program where the cpi is called i've
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct xHandler<'info> {
#[account(mut)]
account_a: Signer<'info>,
#[account(mut
)]
account_b: Box<Account<'info, x>>,
#[account(mut
)]
account_c: Box<Account<'info, z>>,
system_program: Program<'info, System>,
/// CHECK: 
#[account(address = sysvar::instructions::id())]
instructions: AccountInfo<'info>, 
}

impl<'info> xHandler<'info> {
pub fn  set_cfg(
    &mut self,
    bumps: &xHandlerBumps,
    a: u64,
    b: u64,
    c: u64,
    d: u64,
    e: u8,
    f: u64,
    g: u64,
    h: u64,
    i:u8,
    j: u64,
    ) -> Result<()> {

   self.account_b.set_inner(x{ 
        z1 : 0,
        bump: bumps.account_b,
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e,
        f, 
        g, 
        h,
        l: Clock::get()?.epoch,
        i,
        j
    });    
    Ok(())
}
}

Lib.rs
pub fn set_cfg(
    ctx: Context<xHandler>,
    a: u64,
    b: u64,
    c: u64,
    d: u64,
    e: u64,
    f: u64,
    g: u8,
    h: u64,
    i:u8,
    j: u64,
) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.set_cfg(
        &ctx.bumps,
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e,
        f,
        g,
        h,
        i,
        j
        )
       Ok(())
} 

}
Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Fixed by using Instruction::new_with_bytes instead of Instruction::new_with_borsh
